# Quick access to "About Phone" info on an android device through USB and without enabling USB debugging?

Tags: android

I work at a company that processes a lot of phones. We often need to pull information from the phones such as IMEI, S/N, Android Version, etc... I wrote an app that does this but it takes a long time to install and you have to first enable developer options. It's faster to just go through the menus and write the info down yourself.

Instead, is there a way to quickly access information about an Android phone using a USB connection and a program running on the computer without enabling USB debugging?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to access phone info without enabling USB debugging. USB Debugging grants you a level of access to your device. This level of access is important when you need system-level clearance, such as when coding a new app. However, there are a few non-development-related benefits from this new level of access that can give you much more freedom of control over your device. So, you cannot get access in any way except by enable usb debugging.

[Why Is USB Debugging Mode Important?](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/what-is-usb-debugging-mode-on-android-makeuseof-explains/)

Comment: Thanks for your help, that article gave me some good information to work with. I'll try writing an ADB script instead of installing a whole app, that'll probably be faster.